# selectively execute task in ssis control flow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a SSIS package with a control flow containing a bunch of execute sql tasks in a sequence.

I need to check a flag for each of the tasks and run the task if it is set, if not skip and go to the next one.

Each of the these task  executes a stored proc. So i can check in the proc and "Return" if not set. I was looking for a "SSIS" solution if any.

TIA

PS

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Between your control flow tasks, click on the arrow and choose Edit.  When you do this, you get a dialog that allows you to check the "constraint" (success, completion or failure) of the task, an "expression" (i.e. you can have your execute sql task return a value, store that value in a variable, and check the value of that variable in an expression to determine whether to continue down the path you are editing), an "expression and a constraint", and an "expression or a constraint". These last two are the same except for the logic.  "Expression and constraint" requires a true condition on both the expression and the constraint, "expression or constraint" requires a true condition on only one of the expression and the constraint.

Comment: I just have one path. And the steps in that path need to check a flag, if not set then go to the step in the path. IS that possible with  "constraint"?

Comment: No, Constraint only checks the execution status of the task its input is connected to.  If the task Succeeds, then constraint test will be true if set to Success, if the task fails, then constraint test will be true if set to Failure, Constraint is true whenever the task completes if set to Completion.  You want Expression.  In your stored proc, return your flag value as output.  Put that output into a variable. In your path use Expression and test that variable against your condition.  If true the path will pass to the next step in your flow.

Comment: What about the first task?

Comment: @GeorgiG, in many cases I think Amos Wood's answer is superior to mine.  and said as much in comments to him.  His method works generally better in your situation, although I've seen people include tasks that don't do anything just so they can use constraints before the first real task.

Comment: @GeorgiG Just add a dummy task, e. g. an empty sequence container before the first task, and then you have a connector available to your original first task, which is now the second task.

Answer (score 55):

I think your question was the same as mine in which I wanted to control execution of a task "inline" in my control flow.

The easiest way that I have found doesn't involve expression on the data connectors between the control flow objects but rather using expressions on the control object itself and setting the "Disable" value using an expression.  This way on execution, the object is either skipped or not based upon the expression evaluation.

As an example, I wanted to execute a "Execute SQL Task" to remove my indexes based upon whether a variable named "ExtractType" was equal to "Full".  If it was then I wanted to remove the indexes on my tables before doing my full load.

Comment: Good catch, I had forgotten about the expressions there.  It is easy to overlook all of the places in SSIS that you can use expressions.  If I could vote your answer up further I would.  Thanks for answering this!

Comment: Amazing! I'll try that. Thank you VM!