# disable passing sp parameter

Tags: ssis

I have SSIS package where I have for each loop which runs stored procedures. The loop container passes parameters to the stored procedures. In some cases I need to pass all parameters to stored procedure and in other cases I need to pass only one parameter. Is there any way where I can set if parameter should be passed or not? Maybe will be it possible using Expression in Loop container?

Comment: You could handle the logic in a script task that would also call the SP or you can use sequence containers to apply the logic [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530983/ssis-execute-first-task-if-condition-met-else-skip-to-next)

Comment: How about setting a default value for the optional parameters in your stored procedure and accordingly handle them within the stored proc? Then the caller task in the SSIS would have the freedom to pass one or all the parameters. Another approach could be to pass those default value from the SSIS. Either of these techniques would require you know inside the SSIS how exactly you want to call the SP. If you need further help, revert back, and I can provide further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly. Maybe. Probably. As the question stands, it's rather hard to say.

The need is to supply parameters or not based on "logic not supplied in the question." You could have multiple `Execute SQL Tasks` with a precedence constraint turning powering the different tasks.

An alternative take would be to use an Expression for your query and pass the parameters in as part of the text. I called out some reasons you might *not* want to do it over on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288183/parameterized-oledb-source-query/18300508#18300508)

Yet another approach could be that you null out the parameters in a task where needed as @TI [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530983/ssis-execute-first-task-if-condition-met-else-skip-to-next)

If you need specifics, please edit your question to contain specifics.