# SSIS conditional split runs all conditions

Tags: ssis, components, conditional-statements

I have a data flow tasks in which i process two different file types.  Those that have windows data and those which have Unix.  The end results sets 3 package variables.

I use the conditional split "Select Source" to make the two files take different paths.  When I am processing Windows data the Unix branch should never activate. In fact i have placed a Data viewer on it to make sure of this.  it never breaks on any windows records

Each branch has two more Script Components which set the same package variables based on slightly different rules.  If I delete the right branch the left works perfectly.  However, with the right branch in place that branch will still runs ( as seen by the green arrows) although no records meet the criteria.  Also seen by the fact that there are no record numbers between the components

The right branch runs after all the records have been processed on the left. At this point the global variables have the correct value.  Then the right will run for no reason and set them all back to zero.

How can i prevent the right branch from running ?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530983/ssis-execute-first-task-if-condition-met-else-skip-to-next You can also try to use different variables for Windows and Unix, that way the empty branch will only reset its own variables.

Comment: Your count always returns one row, even though there are no records in this branch. Try to find some workaround.

Comment: i have moved the logic into the work flow and out of the data flow.  it's the best workaround i could think of.  Still surprised by the behavior.  No real reason to have it.  Thanks for your help though.